# How can I detect if node is the last one from within node.tpl.php?

Tags: theming

There are a number of variables for the [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) template, like $id that contains the current nodes index number, but how can I figure out if the current node is the last index or how many nodes there are in the current listing?

(I'm using Drupal 7)

Comment: It depends...how is the 'current listing' being generated?

Comment: By a nodequeue view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is not a good idea for Drupal objects to not "know" how they are being used on a page.  When you make them "self-aware" you introduce artificial dependencies that can make changes down the road harder to make, or inadvertently introduce bugs.

In you case, I would handle this in the views templates.  Out of the box, the last row should have a `views-row-last` class on it.

Otherwise, you need to implement a [`template_preprocess_node`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) in your theme.  The view object will be available as `$variables['view']`.  You would need to add logic to check page, view name, etc, to make sure you are doing things in the right place.  Off the top of my head, I forget which properties you need to check; do a `kpr($variables['view'])` and poke around.